# Replace multiple substrings with one expression in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, replace

I would like to delete multiple substrings from one column. I tried the replace function with the following code:

```
select replace('testetstestetststst', 'test'||'et'||'s', '')
    from dual;
```

My expected result is `ttt`, but I get `tstst`.

In R it works with:

```
gsub("test|et|s", "", "testetstestetststst")
```

How can I replace many different substrings with nothing `('')` in a column in clob format in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the REGEXP version of REPLACE:

```
select regexp_replace('testetstestetststst', 'test|et|s', '')
    from dual;
```

In your code, you are concatenating strings, instead of using an OR operator; that is, your code is equivalent to

```
select replace('testetstestetststst', 'testets', '')
    from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regular expressions, you can nest multiple `REPLACE` functions:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             'testetstestetststst',
             'test'
           ),
           'et'
         ),
         's'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can directly use decode function.
select decode(job,'clerk','1','manager','2','salesman','3',4) from emp;

This will replace clerk with 1,manager with 2,salesman with 3 and other values with 4.